# creation of loop in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to sharepoint workflows.
I need to create a loop on the SharePoint 2010 designer which can go through all the items of a specific list and then send a summary mail by having some items from the list.

I do not want to use two different workflows to create this looping effect and need to do it from one workflow itself.

Comment: Workflow is the wrong tool for the job here then, you need a custom timer job. You may want a workflow becuase they're easy to build in SPD but workflow aren't supposed to loop and are specifically designed not to. There are some SharePoint Designer custom actions that might help but its still the wrong tool.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you mean to say that we should create a custom action and write the logic of looping through the list within the custom action.

Comment: If you want to use the SPD interface then a custom action with looping is the way to augment the functionality of SPD workflows. Creating a timer job will give you more control though (or a scheduled PowerShell task would do too).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can achieve what you're asking for without any loops in SPD workflow. Think about how you want to trigger this action.

Let's say users can manually trigger such a notification email. Give them a form (i.e. InfoPath) that queries your list and pulls in the data rows you want to include in your email notification. Set a rule in your form to concat the returned items into a text field. Your Submit button sends the result to a library on which you trigger a simple notification email workflow - in the body you put your text field. You can always have the workflow delete the item after the email has been sent.

There are other options - you could for instance create a page based on parameters with a data view web part setup to filter by whatever you want to include in your summary. Then simply add a link to that page to your notification email and ask the user to access the information that way.

Hope this helps a bit.